# Python Boolean Error With CSV Data Of Different Digit Lenghts

Tags: python, python-3.x

When using this python script I'm having issues with the Boolean operator working with different digit lengths.

```
with open ('data/idata.csv') as pdata: #Import Status CSV
readstatus = csv.reader(pdata, delimiter=',')
for row in readstatus:
    PN = row[0]
    Desc = row[1]
    Min = row[2]
    Stock = row[3]
    Assem = row[4]

    if (Assem == 'No'):
        print(PN+Min+Stock)
        if (Stock<Min):
            p.insert("",0,text=PN,values=(Desc, Stock))
        else:
            print('')
    else:
        print('')
pdata.close()
```

The issue is: 50>25 TRUE; 25>50 FALSE; 150>110 True;

but... 100>25 FALSE...and 12>2 FALSE

note: the print statements are just for debug

Thanks in advance

Comment: My first guess is that the numbers are strings. Have you tried writing `Min = int(row[2])` and `Stock = int(row[3])`?

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> '100'>'25'
False
>>> int('100')>int('25')
True
```

Answer (score 0):

The `csv` module returns strings as cell values. And strings compare to each other in [lexicographical order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order), that is `1`, `11`, `12` and 21`are sorted exactly like`a`,`aa`,`ab`and`ba` would be sorted alphabetically.

In your case, you'd want to convert the values to `int` if they're always whole numbers, or `float` or `Decimal` if they're fractions.

Thus your fixed code

```
with open ('data/idata.csv') as pdata:
    readstatus = csv.reader(pdata, delimiter=',')
    for row in readstatus:
        PN = row[0]
        Desc = row[1]
        Min = int(row[2])
        Stock = int(row[3])
        Assem = row[4]

        if Assem == 'No':
            print(PN, Min, Stock)
            if Stock < Min:
                p.insert("", 0, text=PN, values=(Desc, Stock))
            else:
                print('')
        else:
            print('')
```

(also do note that you need not close `pdata` as that is what the `with` statement is for!)